# Programmatically create page when saving custom post type post

Tags: php, wp-admin, admin

I want to create page when saving new post on my CPT and i want it to be created only when first saving (by pressing Publish button) that post, not when i click Add new (it then saves the post first time, sets it's status as auto-draft and gets the ID for your so called future post for avoiding race conditions)

My code is following (all in class scope):

```
add_action('wp_insert_post', [$this, 'onPostDelete'], 99);

function onPostSave($postID)
{
    $rev = wp_is_post_revision( $postID );

    if ($rev) {
        $postID = $rev;
    }

    $pT = get_post($postID);


    // If we are dealing with kookon CPT
    if ($pT->post_type === 'kookon') {

        // $postID refers to created post ID
        // $pT refers to created post object
        // $kookonPageID refers to page that is created programmatically for corresponding $pT (if $pT is post type `kookon`

        // This is parent kookon post, which will create page with the same name
        if ($pT->post_parent == 0) {

            // If the corresponding page for kookon does not yet exists
            if (!$this->kookonPageExists($postID)) {

                // *** HERE LIES THE PROBLEM ***
                // Removing 3 lines below fixes my problem but creates another
                if ($pT->post_status == 'auto-draft') {
                    return true;
                }

                // This kookon does not exists, create all pages related to it
                return $this->createKookonPage($pT);
            } else {

                $slug = get_post_meta($pT->ID, 'kookon_page_slug', true);

                $this->updateKookonPage($pT, $this->getKookonPageID($pT->ID), 0,[
                    'post_name' => $slug,
                    'meta_fields' => [
                        '_wp_page_template' => 'kookon_main',
                        '_kookon_cpt_id' => $pT->ID
                    ]
                ]);

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

function createKookonPage($pT, $pageParentID = 0, $opts = [])
{
    $postID = $pT->ID;

    if ($pageParentID == 0) {
        $title = "Kookon: $pT->post_title";
    } else {
        $title = $pT->post_title;
    }

    $slug = isset($opts['post_name']) ? $opts['post_name'] : '';

    $result = wp_insert_post([
        'post_title'  => $title,
        'post_name'   => !empty($slug) ? sanitize_title($slug) : sanitize_title(get_the_title($postID)),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type'   => 'page',
        'post_parent' => $pageParentID,
        'meta_input'  => [
            '_kookon_cpt_id'    => $postID,
            '_wp_page_template' => isset($opts['template']) ? $opts['template'] : 'default'
        ]
    ]);
```

So currently what happens with this code is if i save post the pages are created, and everything seems correct in wp_posts table. They are also showing up (i have WPML installed) as Published page count, but not in the list where i could press Edit, delete etc...

I also use `wp_insert_post` hook instead of `save_post` because using save_post for some reason dont let my ACF fields that are set for my kookon CPT to save, when i do save the inputs show up aa empty and nothing changes in DB, using `wp_insert_post` clears that error for some reason...

Any ideas?